# .prop("checked", false) makes checkbox true

Tags: jquery, checkbox, checked, prop

I have some `<input value=name type=checkbox>` whose values must be persistent. So I stored in Cookies the value of every of them, and I wrote a function which must restore the values when the page is ready.

The function which save the cookies is:

```
function setAllCookies() {
    var checkboxs = $("#divwheretheinputsare input");
    for (i in checkboxs)
        Cookies.set(checkboxs[i].value,checkboxs[i].checked);
}
```

And the function to restore them is:

```
function readAllCookies() {
    var checkboxs = $("#divwheretheinputsare input");
    for (i in checkboxs) {
        var nom = checkboxs[i].value;
        var value = Cookies.get(nom);
        $("##divwheretheinputsare input[value='" + nom + "']").prop("checked", value);
    //Also tried $("##divwheretheinputsare input[value='" + nom + "']")[0].checked = value;
    }
}
```

I can confirm the Cookies are stored with the correct name and the two functions are completly executed. With debugging, I detect this: When the line $("##divwheretheinputsare input[value='" + nom + "']").prop("checked", value) is executed, the checkbox always turn checked, no matter if value is false. If I execute that exact line in console, the checkbox change correctly...

Also, the alternative codeline, is correctly executed in the console but in the function it drops: "TypeError: $(...)[0] is undefined".

Comment: cookies store strings but you need a boolean for `prop('checked', boolean)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [charlieftl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) mentioned your value is coming in as a string ("true" or "false") not (true or false) and any value in the prop("checked",value) field will be taken as true.

Try:

`var value = (Cookies.get(nom) == 'true');`

That will set your value to a boolean rather than a string.